# Angular reactive form - checkboxes - Initialize formArray with exisitng array

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms, angular2-forms

I have an dynamic array of lkBoardTypeList list fetched from server. I want to push that array to form array on initialization, basically i want to show checkboxes based on Board name or id in array. I know how to push an empty array in reactive forms.but how to initialize with an existing array.Actually its an update/edit Component

```
export class BoardTypeList{
id number;
descr string;
}
```

component :

```
lkBoardTypeList: LkBoardType[] = []; 
SelectedLkBoardTypeList: LkBoardType[] = []; 

this.boardDashboardForm = this.formBuilder.group({
                    id: new FormControl(this.boardObj.id, Validators.required),
                    location: new FormControl(this.boardObj.location),
                    boardType: new FormArray([])
                 });
this.addCheckBoxes();

..//..//

 addCheckBoxes(){
        this.lkBoardTypeList.forEach(() => this.boardTypeFormArray.push(new FormControl(false)));
    }

 get boardTypeFormArray(){ 
        return this.boardDashboardForm.controls.boardType as FormArray;
    }

loadSelected(event){
    
        this.boardService.getBoardTypeById(event.value).subscribe( posts =>{
            this.data = posts; 
            console.log('getBoardTypeById',this.data);
            },
            error => { 
            console.log('getBoardTypeById - error',error);
            this._errorService.handleError(error); 
            }, 
            () => {   
            this.SelectedLkBoardTypeList = this.data.boardTypes;
            for (let i = 0; i < this.lkBoardTypeList.length; i++) {
            ..///.. what code goes here
            }
            }); 
}
```

And in the HTML

```
<div class="row">
                
                <div class="col-sm-2">                
                    <p-dropdown [options]="boardArray" formControlName="id"  (onChange)="loadSelected($event)" placeholder=" Select "></p-dropdown> 
                </div>
                
            </div>
    <div class="form-group" >
                        <div formArrayName="boardType" *ngFor="let c of boardTypeFormArray.controls; let i = index">
                            <input class="col-sm-1" type="checkbox" [formGroupName]="i"/>
                            <span class="col-sm-5" >{{lkBoardTypeList[i].descr}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

RightNow when I inspect element I see formArrayName="boardType" and checkbox element as follows:

```
<input class="col-sm-1 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" type="checkbox" ng-reflect-name="0">
<input class="col-sm-1 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" type="checkbox" ng-reflect-name="1">
<input class="col-sm-1 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" type="checkbox" ng-reflect-name="2">
```

I am guessing the ng-reflect-name="0" is nothing but value of 'i'. What am trying to set value of the array with id from lkBoardTypeList which is 10,20,30.

Also please let me know how to set the values for checked in the checkboxes.
SelectedLkBoardTypeList - say for example the entire list has values (10,20,30). selectedList contains only 10 and it has to be checked.

Comment: This is how it has to work. When the page loads up initially all the checkboxes should be unchecked. But I want ng-reflect-name="10", ng-reflect-name="20",ng-reflect-name="30" which maps the id from lkBoardTypeList. Next When the dropDown in the page changes I get the selectedLkBoardTypeList. Now i check to see what should be checked and unchecked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should use `[formControlName]="i"` instead of `[formGroupName]="i"`

`ng-reflect-${name}` attribute is added for debugging purposes and shows the input bindings that a component/directive has declared in its class.

`FormControlName` directive declares

```
@Input('formControlName') name!: string|number|null;
```

So, you're right: `ng-reflect-name="0"` describes value you're passing in `formControlName` input.

---

If you want to prepopulate FormArray with `SelectedLkBoardTypeList` then you can just check if specific item exists in `SelectedLkBoardTypeList`. Let's say you have:

```
SelectedLkBoardTypeList: LkBoardType[] = [
  {
    id: 10,
    descr: 'Type 1'
  }
];
```

then your `addCheckBoxes` method should be as follows:

```
addCheckBoxes() {
  this.lkBoardTypeList.forEach((type) => {
    const selected = this.SelectedLkBoardTypeList.some(x => x.id === type.id);
    this.boardTypeFormArray.push(new FormControl(selected))
  });
}
```

Finally, if you want to get selected items during post execution you can map selected values in FormArray to your original array:

```
save() {
  const model = this.boardDashboardForm.value;

  const selectedTypes = model.boardType.filter(Boolean).map((_, i) => this.lkBoardTypeList[i]);
  console.log(selectedTypes);
}
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/HXM0iek18k9sPgPDYBvN)**

Comment: thank you. One question? When the page loads up initially the checkboxes should all be unchecked but the formCOntrolName should have value of 10,20,30 what change does that require in the adCheckBoxes method? The selectedLkBoardTypeList is only when I change abother dropdown element in the html file.I changed formGroupName to formControlName.

Comment: If they are all unchecked then all values should be false

Comment: my addcheckBoxes will initially have false addCheckBoxes(){
        this.lkBoardTypeList.forEach(() => this.boardTypeFormArray.push(new FormControl(false)));
    }  So ng-reflect-name="0", I want this to hold ng-reflect-name="10" or 20, 30 with unchecked and when I change the dropDown I will see which one should be selected and have the selected code on it.

Comment: i have added a comment to my question

Comment: Where is the dropdown in your page? Why do you want to look at that `ng-reflect-name` attribute which is debug only attribute?

Comment: i have updated my question. Requirement is as follows: When the page load initially checkboxes should be all false. But im assuming ng-reflect-name="10" should hold lkBoardTypeList "id" values. Im having java/JSTL background not angular which is new so not sure what ng-reflect-name="0" means. When my dropDown changes I will call loadSelected method to check only those checkBoxes say id=10 as checked. So i am assuming this ng-reflect-name="0" should hold ng-reflect-name="10", only then i can assign it when dropdown changes. Please correctme if im wrong.

Comment: I updated my demo https://ng-run.com/edit/HXM0iek18k9sPgPDYBvN?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts Please take a look at generated html. Actual value is inside `data-value` attribue. So you will have data-value="10 data-value="20" etc But I really don't understand why you need this

Comment: i see that initially its loaded with false and all checkboxes are unchecked. fine. Now the loadSelected() has to be updated to keep the checkbox with id=10 as checked. How do i do it? The code I have updates checkbox to false initially.  how should my code look in the loadSelected() method to check checkbox with id=10 and uncheck id-20,30

Comment: I updated demo https://ng-run.com/edit/HXM0iek18k9sPgPDYBvN?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts On loadSelected it should select 10 and 30

Comment: thank you. But still need help with this one. Please check my updated loadSelected(event){} method. The return value from the service has the selected board. Can you help me with code in the for loop. My issue is when im trying to assign the SelectedLkBoardTypeList in the for loop to the selected list. Thanks for the patience. This is pretty new to me.

Comment: What is the `boardsList`? I don't see it in your code. Is it `lkBoardTypeList`?

Comment: Let me a minute

Comment: Please ignore that. SelectedLkBoardTypeList  and lkBoardTypeList are the 2 list values. lkBoardTypeList  has all values (10,20,30) unchecked initially. SelectedLkBoardTypeList  is the list that holds the value that needs to be checked. say (10,20). I dont have access to stackblitz from my laptop sorry.

Comment: If `SelectedLkBoardTypeList` is an array of `LkBoardType` then it should be like this `this.boardTypeFormArray.patchValue(this.lkBoardTypeList.map(item => selectedLkBoardTypeList.some(type => type.id === item.id))` 
      )

Comment: You can check it here https://ng-run.com/edit/1k3nE4GNbl7Rizj6Vosa